# compare character to string C

Tags: c

I need to write a program that will intake a character and compare it against an array( the ascii table)

```
char asciiname[] =
        "NUL\0"  "SOH\0"  "STX\0"  "ETX\0"  "EOT\0"  "ENQ\0"  "ACK\0"  "BEL\0"
        " BS\0"  " HT\0"  " NL\0"  " VT\0"  " NP\0"  " CR\0"  " SO\0"  " SI\0"
        "DLE\0"  "DC1\0"  "DC2\0"  "DC3\0"  "DC4\0"  "NAK\0"  "SYN\0"  "ETB\0"
        "CAN\0"  " EM\0"  "SUB\0"  "ESC\0"  " FS\0"  " GS\0"  " RS\0"  " VS\0"
        " SP\0"  "  !\0"  "  \"\0" "  #\0"  "  $\0"  "  %\0"  "  &\0"  "  '\0"
        "  (\0"  "  )\0"  "  *\0"  "  +\0"  "  ,\0"  "  -\0"  "  .\0"  "  /\0"
        "  0\0"  "  1\0"  "  2\0"  "  3\0"  "  4\0"  "  5\0"  "  6\0"  "  7\0"
        "  8\0"  "  9\0"  "  :\0"  "  ;\0"  "  <\0"  "  =\0"  "  >\0"  "  ?\0"
        "  @\0"  "  A\0"  "  B\0"  "  C\0"  "  D\0"  "  E\0"  "  F\0"  "  G\0"
        "  H\0"  "  I\0"  "  J\0"  "  K\0"  "  L\0"  "  M\0"  "  N\0"  "  O\0"
        "  P\0"  "  Q\0"  "  R\0"  "  S\0"  "  T\0"  "  U\0"  "  V\0"  "  W\0"
        "  X\0"  "  Y\0"  "  Z\0"  "  [\0"  "  \\\0" "  ]\0"  "  ^\0"  "  _\0"
        "  `\0"  "  a\0"  "  b\0"  "  c\0"  "  d\0"  "  e\0"  "  f\0"  "  g\0"
        "  h\0"  "  i\0"  "  j\0"  "  k\0"  "  l\0"  "  m\0"  "  n\0"  "  o\0"
        "  p\0"  "  q\0"  "  r\0"  "  s\0"  "  t\0"  "  u\0"  "  v\0"  "  w\0"
        "  x\0"  "  y\0"  "  z\0"  "  {\0"  "  |\0"  "  }\0"  "  ~\0"  "DEL\0"
        ;
```

The input will be }~a,bz\Z.  I need to take each character and compare it against the array above and if there is a match print out the hex of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
int getline1(char s[], int max);
main ()
{
int len, i, j;
char line[MAXLINE];
char asciiname[] =
    "NUL\0"  "SOH\0"  "STX\0"  "ETX\0"  "EOT\0"  "ENQ\0"  "ACK\0"  "BEL\0"
    " BS\0"  " HT\0"  " NL\0"  " VT\0"  " NP\0"  " CR\0"  " SO\0"  " SI\0"
    "DLE\0"  "DC1\0"  "DC2\0"  "DC3\0"  "DC4\0"  "NAK\0"  "SYN\0"  "ETB\0"
    "CAN\0"  " EM\0"  "SUB\0"  "ESC\0"  " FS\0"  " GS\0"  " RS\0"  " VS\0"
    " SP\0"  "  !\0"  "  \"\0" "  #\0"  "  $\0"  "  %\0"  "  &\0"  "  '\0"
    "  (\0"  "  )\0"  "  *\0"  "  +\0"  "  ,\0"  "  -\0"  "  .\0"  "  /\0"
    "  0\0"  "  1\0"  "  2\0"  "  3\0"  "  4\0"  "  5\0"  "  6\0"  "  7\0"
    "  8\0"  "  9\0"  "  :\0"  "  ;\0"  "  <\0"  "  =\0"  "  >\0"  "  ?\0"
    "  @\0"  "  A\0"  "  B\0"  "  C\0"  "  D\0"  "  E\0"  "  F\0"  "  G\0"
    "  H\0"  "  I\0"  "  J\0"  "  K\0"  "  L\0"  "  M\0"  "  N\0"  "  O\0"
    "  P\0"  "  Q\0"  "  R\0"  "  S\0"  "  T\0"  "  U\0"  "  V\0"  "  W\0"
    "  X\0"  "  Y\0"  "  Z\0"  "  [\0"  "  \\\0" "  ]\0"  "  ^\0"  "  _\0"
    "  `\0"  "  a\0"  "  b\0"  "  c\0"  "  d\0"  "  e\0"  "  f\0"  "  g\0"
    "  h\0"  "  i\0"  "  j\0"  "  k\0"  "  l\0"  "  m\0"  "  n\0"  "  o\0"
    "  p\0"  "  q\0"  "  r\0"  "  s\0"  "  t\0"  "  u\0"  "  v\0"  "  w\0"
    "  x\0"  "  y\0"  "  z\0"  "  {\0"  "  |\0"  "  }\0"  "  ~\0"  "DEL\0"
    ;



        while ((len = getline1(line, MAXLINE)) != 0) {
            for(i = 0; i < len;i++){

                        printf("The code %3x represents %s\n", line[i], &asciiname[4*line[i]]);

            }
        }
} 

int getline1(char s[], int max) {
    int i, c;
    for (i=0; i<max-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

I am new to C and cannot seem to figure out how the compare would work between character and the string in the asciiname array.  any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is the final code that i ended up using thanks to the help below.

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding explicit `\0` characters to all your strings? C string literals automatically get a null byte at the end, so you'll have **two** nulls in all your strings.

Comment: That's not how you compare strings.  That's why we have `strcmp`

Comment: @Bramar there are no `,` so it's just a large string with explicit embeded `'\0'`'s

Comment: @iharob Ahh, missed that. That also explains the `4*j` I was wondering about.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? all you need is an array of `char *` and then `array[chr]` will be the name of the character.

Comment: There is no need to 'compare strings'. For instance, the *character* `0x1B` (27, in decimal) will never compare to the *string* "ESC". You can simply grab the *n*-th element in the name array, where *n* is the character code. (Only if *n* < 128, for (hopefully) obvious reasons.)

Comment: the way the asciiname table is defined results in a continuous set of strings, when each string is separated by a '\0'  however, that does NOT produce an array that can be accessed via asciiname[x].   see the answer by @iharob for the correct way to define the array.  With the correct way, the actual contents of the array is a series of pointers into readonly memory.  In the readonly memory is the actual strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are doing it like that, but check this example of how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *asciiname[128] = {
    "NUL",  "SOH",  "STX",  "ETX",  "EOT",  "ENQ",  "ACK",  "BEL",
     "BS",   "HT",   "NL",   "VT",   "NP",   "CR",   "SO",   "SI",
    "DLE",  "DC1",  "DC2",  "DC3",  "DC4",  "NAK",  "SYN",  "ETB",
    "CAN",   "EM",  "SUB",  "ESC",   "FS",   "GS",   "RS",   "VS",
    " SP",    "!",    "\"",   "#",    "$",    "%",    "&",    "'",
      "(",    ")",    "*",    "+",    ",",    "-",    ".",    "/",
      "0",    "1",    "2",    "3",    "4",    "5",    "6",    "7",
      "8",    "9",    ":",    ";",    "<",    "=",    ">",    "?",
      "@",    "A",    "B",    "C",    "D",    "E",    "F",    "G",
      "H",    "I",    "J",    "K",    "L",    "M",    "N",    "O",
      "P",    "Q",    "R",    "S",    "T",    "U",    "V",    "W",
      "X",  "  Y",  "  Z",  "  [",  "  \\",   "]",    "^",    "_",
      "`",  "  a",  "  b",  "  c",  "  d",    "e",    "f",    "g",
      "h",  "  i",  "  j",  "  k",  "  l",    "m",    "n",    "o",
      "p",  "  q",  "  r",  "  s",  "  t",    "u",    "v",    "w",
      "x",  "  y",  "  z",  "  {",  "  |",    "}",    "~",  "DEL"
    };

int
main(void)
{
    int chr;

    while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'))
    {
        if (chr > 127)
            continue;
        printf("The code 0x%3x represents: %3s\n", chr, asciiname[chr]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see now that i don't need to do a compare and i can just use the ascii value of the input as the look up number in the array.  thanks a lot this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a search: your `asciiname` is organized in such a way that `asciiname[charValue]` would produce the proper string representation, so all you need is an index look-up.

```
for(i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    printf("%c - %s\n", line[i], &asciiname[4*line[i]]);
}
```

Comment: They're not null terminators. It's one long char array with nulls every 4 bytes, not an array of strings.

Comment: @Barmar Oops, I so missed that he did not put commas in there! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks i missed that i could just do a lookup and not have to do a compare and that the ascii value of the input would bring me right there.